# How to get Twitter Typeahead 0.10 and Bloodhound work together in a require/backbone(1.1.2)-setup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, requirejs, typeahead.js, bloodhound

Is there any working example somewhere to find? Typeahead is working well, but when I try to connect Bloodhound to it, I allways get the error

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tokenizers' of undefined*

In my Backbone-main.js I have defined a

```
path: {..., 

        typeahead: 'libs/typeahead.jquery.min',
        bloodhound: 'libs/bloodhound.min',
}
```

with

```
shim: { ..., 
            'typeahead': {
                'deps': ['jquery'],
                'exports': 'jquery' // Make sure the noconflict configuration of jquery doesn't break this extension
            },
            'bloodhound':{
                'deps': ['jquery'],
                'exports': 'jquery' // Make sure the noconflict configuration of jquery doesn't break this extension
            },
```

}

and in my Backbone.view I define

```
define(['backbone', 'typeahead', 'bloodhound', '../models/searchableDocument', '../collections/searchableDocuments', 'text!./asset_footer.html'],
function(Backbone, Typeahead, Bloodhound, SearchableDocument, SearchableDocuments, footerTmpl) { ...

//.../initialize/...
var docHound = new Bloodhound({
                name: 'documents',
                local: this.allDocuments.toJSON(),
                datumTokenizer: function(doc) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(doc.name); },
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace

            });
            docHound.initialize();
...
```

I also have included Bootstrap (2.3.2) in my system-structure so I also tried to work around a possible conflict by using

```
...
var DocHound = Bloodhound.noConflict();
            var docHound = new DocHound({
...
```

but this just throws the error

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'noConflict' of undefined*

so its more looking like I don't 'reach' the Bloodhound-Clas at all...
Any hints? Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and just needed to add Bloodhound as an export.

```
    "bloodhound": {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports: "Bloodhound"
    }
```

HTH!